# Delete rows based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

So column 1 consists of various names, and I want to delete the entire row if the name in a particular cell in that column is not of a subset of names. I tried using a nested If coupled with a For to go through the rows but it turns out deleting rows in ascending order is not working. 
Now, I want the for loop to start from the final value to the initial one, and I used "Step -1" at the end like this

```
For Each a In Range("F2:F244") Step-1
```

But I'm getting a

> Compile error: End of statement

What am I doing wrong? Or is there any other way to delete the rows?

Edit: With @Skin's suggestion, the following is the updated code. But now the error reads

> Run Time Error '1004': Unable to set the Delete property of the Range Class

```
Sub deleteaccount()

Dim x As Range, l As Long

Set x = Range("E2:E244")

For l = x.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To x.Cells(1, 1).Row Step -1
    If Left(Cells(l, 5), 4) = "DARL" Then
        Cells(l, 6).Value = "darling"

    ElseIf Left(Cells(l, 5), 4) = "GIRI" Then
            Cells(l, 6).Value = "girias"

        ElseIf Left(Cells(l, 5), 4) = "S.C." Then
                Cells(l, 6).Value = "sc shah"

            ElseIf Left(Cells(l, 5), 4) = "SHAR" Then
                    Cells(l, 6).Value = "sharpatronics"

                ElseIf Left(Cells(l, 5), 4) = "VASA" Then
                        Cells(l, 6).Value = "vasanth"

                    ElseIf Left(Cells(l, 5), 4) = "VIVE" Then
                            Cells(l, 6).Value = "viveks"

                        Else
                            Cells(l, 6).EntireRow.Delete = True

    End If

Next l

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Dim objRange As Range, lngRow As Long

Set objRange = Range("F2:F244")

With objRange
    For lngRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row To .Cells(1, 1).Row Step -1
        If .Cells(lngRow, 1) = "THE_VALUE" Then .Rows(lngRow).Delete
    Next
End With
```

Comment: @JRBatHolmes is that a question or a statement?

Comment: now there is a "Run time error: Unable to set the Delete property of the Range" when debugging

Comment: @JRBatHolmes can you paste the rest of your code into the question?  Also, I updated my answer slightly, potential oversight that wouldn't be a problem for your scenario but updated anyway.

Comment: See my solution.  .Rows(lngRow).Delete ... it's a method, not a property, therefore, you can't set it to True, you simply invoke it.